# git commit -v problem with Mac OS X?

Tags: git

I setup TextMate (mate -w) for editing message for committing with git as follows.

```
git config --global core.editor "mate -w"
```

The problem is when I run 'git commit -v', instead of TextMate, COMMIT_EDITMSG is open with other editor (for my case, Aquamcs), and I can see the error message in command line.

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

What's wrong with this?

### SOLVED

mipadi helped me to solve this issue. I had a GIT_EDITOR environment variable set in my .bashrc file. After removing this one, everything works fine.

Comment: Do you have the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable set? That is preferred ahead of `core.editor`.

Answer (score 0):

And you can set `EDITOR` in your .bashrc to be less specific. This saves time if you always want to use the the same editor.